# Use Jquery to add a div on hover of input type image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I can not modify html elements except through a script.

I have a page that has several buttons
They do not have IDs
Goal is simple:
Float a div under the buttons to add "tips" and information what they are for

This mess of a erp system has some odd cluetip jquery stuff running. I was able to dynamically add title attribute but then had problems turning it into a tool tip type thing. So I abandoned that esp since it was noted code is no longer supported. I decided jquery and hide/ show divs

I am new to jquery

So two things
1) This script below only triggers the first div - oddly nothing happens for the second and third ?

2) If I have 7 buttons - can I name the div id the same as my buttons and use a (this) to reference. I tried unsuccessfully . But it seems much more efficient then writing 8 conditions literally referencing them.

Too much time so I'm looking to all you insanely talented jquery to help pinpoint why this isn't working for me and how to go about it.

Code is

```
    <script>
$(".ShoppingList_UpdateListButton").hover(
  function () {
    $("div#ShoppingList_UpdateListButton").show();
  }, 
  function () {
    $("div#ShoppingList_UpdateListButton").hide();
  }
);
$(".ButtonAddListToCart").hover(
  function () {
    $("div#ButtonAddListToCart").show();
  }, 
  function () {
    $("div#ButtonAddListToCart").hide();
  }
);
$(".ButtonEmptyList").hover(
  function () {
    $("div#ButtonEmptyList").show();
  }, 
  function () {
    $("div#ButtonEmptyList").hide();
  }
);

</script>
<div id="ButtonEmptyList" style="display: none;">Click this to DELETE this list.</div>
<div id="ButtonAddListToCart" style="display: none;">Click this to add ENTIRE list above, and current quantities displayed to your shopping cart.</div>
<div id="ShoppingList_UpdateListButton" style="display: none;">Click this to update your list. </div>
```

EDIT TO POST

This will help... here is how the button appears on the page.
You'll notice I'm referencing the class since it doesn't have an ID attribute

```
<input type="image" name="ButtonUpdateList" src="/contentonly.aspx?file=images/buttons/updatelist_b.gif" class="ShoppingList_UpdateListButton" title="Click this to update your list.">
```

Comment: the references using class ie - ".ButtonEmptyList" on top - I can not change

Comment: You should provide a fiddle of your case. With buttons, divs and your current script ... then we could fix it ;)

Comment: You can't have the same ID twice, ID's should be unique. It will work but it's not a good practice.

Comment: I'm aware id's are unique. Where do I have a duplicate above? 3 id's of the div are unique.  
The buttons I'm referencing are not set as ID - they are set as name= in a type=image -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have only one class on each button, you can try something like :

HTML:

```
<button class="ref1">REF1</button>
<div id="ref1">REF1's div ...</div>
<button class="ref2">REF2</button>
<div id="ref2">REF2's div ...</div>
<button class="ref3">REF3</button>
<div id="ref3">REF3's div ...</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.ref1, .ref2, .ref3')
.hover(function () {
    var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#' + myClass).show();
}, function(){
    var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#' + myClass).hide();
});
```

**JSFIDDLE** : http://fiddle.jshell.net/msieurtoph/rwj59m8d/

---

The coma in the jQuery selector lets you have as many selectors as you need in the same set.

You could have done this this way too :

```
$('.ref1').add('.ref2').add('.ref3').hover(...);
```

or if you need to do it sequentially/programmatically :

```
mySelection = $('.ref1');
mySelection = mySelection.add('.ref2');
mySelection = mySelection.add('.ref3');
mySelection.hover(...);
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't need sequentially.. and at first your code was doing the same as mine - only triggering the first. I realize there was an adjustment that had to be done and names and class were mixed up.

I left all my code alone and plugged in your piece here!  
And it worked like a charm!

    $('.ref1, .ref2, .ref3')
.hover(function () {
    var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#' + myClass).show();
}, function(){
    var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#' + myClass).hide();
});

Comment: ;) I only gave you an example, using simpler names/classes. Good if it helped.